# Dynamic Tiles Template with Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dynamic, tiles2

I'm currently developping an application with Spring 3 and Tiles 2.

I have a question regarding Tiles and the dynamic contents.

I would like to have a "header" template, that contains a menu that is populated with database information.

As the menu is available through the application, i would like not to put the information in the request controller.

Do you have any information ?

Thanks

Comment: please provide more information as to how its all wired up?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I decided to use a viewpreparer from tiles :). But maybe, you had an other answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a ViewPreparer on the menu definition.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial](http://tech.finn.no/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/) that can help you with

- spring to tiles integration,
- definitions with wildcards,
- implementing a fallback pattern using the OptionsRenderer, and
- definitions composition.

http://tech.finn.no/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/